# Extended type typechecking with factory method and known input parameters

Tags: typescript

Pardon me for possibly bad title, not sure how to describe this:

I have interfaces **A** and **B**:

```
interface A {
    prop1: string
    prop2: object
}

interface B {
    prop3: number
}
```

And interface **C** which further refines **A**:

```
interface C extends A {
    prop2: {
        objectProperty: string
    }
}
```

Then I have function that returns objects of type **A**:

```
function func1(arg1: string, arg2: object): A {
    return {
        prop1: arg1,
        prop2: arg2
    }
}
```

And another one that returns objects of type **B**:

```
function func2(arg1: number): B {
    return {
        prop3: arg1
    }
}
```

And finally a function which should return objects of type **C** *or* **B**, building them using the first two function:

```
function func3(): C | B {
    if(...) {
        return func1('some string', { objectProperty: 'another string' });
    } else {
        return func2(100);
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve, is to ensure that the return value of the first branch is checked against type *C* and get a warning, if it's not. For example:

```
        return func1('some string', { someOtherProperty: 'another string' });
```

should yield a warning, since someOtherProperty does not exist in type C.

Not sure if this makes any sense... the reasoning behind this is, that I have multiple interfaces extending A, and I would like to have a single factory method to build them using given input object and still be able to ensure that the resulting object is what I want it to be. Might just be that I'm trying to make a complex problem from a simple thing... but I imagine it should be possible somehow this way?

Comment: The compiler has no idea that `func1()` returns values of type `C`.  If you want that to be true you need to change its type signature, possibly like  [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA78Zw).  Does that meet your needs?  If so, I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate by providing a [mcve] that demonstrates what should succeed and what should fail.  Good luck!

Comment: That could work. The thing is, that there will be a lot of extended types that `func1` would return. The signature would not be pretty. Then again not sure if there is anything pretty in this idea :-)

Comment: Maybe you want `func1()` to be generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpl07m) then?  A good [mcve] should have enough use case info in it so that it is straightforward to see whether a proposed solution meets your needs.  If you have multiple interfaces extending `A` and need `func1()` to output all of them depending on its input, then show at least two of them.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and you nailed the example! Thanks a lot, and sorry for not providing better example in the first hand. Still learning typescript, I tried to figure out how to do it with generics but I couldn't get it right. Do you want to answer the question and I'll accept it, or should I answer myself (credit due to you of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to change the example code to highlight the issue. Here we have an interface `A`, and two different extensions of it `B` and `C`, where one of the properties from `A` is narrowed:

```
interface A {
    prop1: string
    prop2: object
}

interface B extends A {
    prop2: {
        bProp: string;
    }
}

interface C extends A {
    prop2: {
        cProp: string
    }
}
```

The function `makeA` accepts parameters corresponding to `prop1` and `prop2` of `A` and returns a value of type `A`:

```
function makeA(arg1: string, arg2: object): A {
    return {
        prop1: arg1,
        prop2: arg2
    }
}
```

But if we try to use it to make strongly typed `B` and `C` instances, we run into problems:

```
function makeBOrC(): B | C {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return makeA('', { bProp: '' }); // error! A is not assignable to B | C
    } else {
        return makeA('', { cProp: '' }); // error! A is not assignable to B | C
    }
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can we fix it?

---

It happens because the compiler sees the return type of `makeA()` as just `A`. The type of the value you pass in for the second argument, such as `{ bProp: '' }`, is widened to `object`, no matter what.  The output type, `A`, is not incorrect, but it is too wide for your purposes.  The compiler has forgotten information that you need it to keep track of.

---

Fix #1: Type assertions

Sometimes there are situations where you just know more about the type of some value than the compiler does, and there's no reasonable way to make the compiler figure it out.  (For this example code there *is* such a way, but it's not always possible, so it's useful to consider such situations.)  When this happens, you always have the option of using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that a certain value has a certain type... and the compiler will generally believe you.  So one fix is to do that inside `makeBOrC()`:

```
function makeBOrC(): B | C {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return origMakeA('', { bProp: '' }) as B; // assert
    } else if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return origMakeA('', { cProp: '' }) as C; // assert
    } else {
        return origMakeA('', { oops: 123 }) as B; // <-- no error here either
    }
}
```

The `as B` and `as C` tell the compiler to take what it thinks of as being just type `A` and treat it as a `B` or a `C` respectively.  This makes the errors go away.  But note that when you use a type assertion you are shifting the responsibility for verifying type safety away from the compiler and onto you.  If you make a mistake and end up lying to the compiler, it can't catch it... so type assertions are best used sparingly and with great care.  The line above with `{oops: 123}` shows such a case where we have lied to the compiler, and there is no error.

---

Fix #2: Generics

For this example, though, the fix is to make `makeA()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the second argument:

```
function makeA<T extends object>(arg1: string, arg2: T) {
    return {
        prop1: arg1,
        prop2: arg2
    }
}
```

I've removed the return type annotation `A`, and let the compiler infer it from the implementation.  IntelliSense shows the type signature as follows:

```
/* function makeA<T extends object>(arg1: string, arg2: T): {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: T;
} */
```

So the output type of `makeA()` depends on the input type of `arg2`, and so it should be possible to keep track of the type of `arg2`.  Do note that nothing explicitly says that `makeA()` produces an `A`; but you will find that TypeScript's [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) makes such explicitness unnecessary.  The compiler understand that `makeA()` produces values assignable to `A` anyway:

```
function foo<T extends object>(x: T) {
    const a: A = makeA("", x); // okay
}
```

Once we make `makeA()` generic, the `makeBOrC()` function will work as desired:

```
function makeBOrC(): B | C {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return makeA('', { bProp: '' }); // okay, assignable to B
    } else if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return makeA('', { cProp: '' }); // okay, assignable to C
    } else {
        return makeA('', { oops: 123 }); // error! 
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <---
        //Type '{ prop1: string; prop2: { oops: number; }; }' is 
        //not assignable to type 'B | C'.
    }
}
```

Here you can see that the compiler is happy with the lines with `bProp` and `cProp`, as it understands that they produce something assignable to `B | C`.  Even better, the line with `oops` results in an error: the compiler is maintaining type safety by warning you that output type is not assignable to `B | C`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAOUA9oQIwBcyAzmFKAOa4FGmEBM1JARgFYQEYXAF9cuUJFiIUAIWQQAHpBAATGmkwsCxMly15WBHgAV21OgxCMA3NvxicjieGjwkyAMILlENRvRsQ3xdTmogowIEMzILeiZ7ZEdnHFwYAFcQIWASEGQSBkYAWTgAawhUAAo4KEYqWnjrABpkGsZ9XgEhAEpqQMSoCDB0qDyIyLYyerbyJsTWUP02jkTk8RwMrLAcvIBbMohZAHkoT1QaGmgwSt7keQAfLwNWYBhkSpKwAAsAOig4NQkXY3ZAAHmQAAYfgBWbrPCaDYajfKFErlKoAcgxLQwyFM5mQWKS3RsyAA9GSFFBSFAAISaYAaEAkMCtC7ARggOA8AA2KDAJDuyEenlWCh5l3hkURIzyBQ5aIqlSxOOQ0QJRJEJPJlOgNPp6EZyGZrLg7M53L5yAFQpFq1E6022VyyH25WOp3Olyg11uDye43wr3en1+-0BwLh4KhsKlRhlyPlxQOmOxmDxMUI1E1cLNd1JFLZ3uEwSS4slwY+cG+fwBqiBIOjMLhgfjQ1lKIVKeVadx6tihIxxLZXgLlLNxbFEAlKFbrATctR3ZV6ZIZBo1HIHAAzMO87Ix2CALRH42CvUFZBfaAQe1OdaOzLOvYp0EAFR8KnU+X4gjAAD5qlqepLCYFplmoN8WwGdtkTnHR2GmYC5lLBZ2CWWoVlLNYcDJAAqZAnW2F03Qqd9Pz8b9Oj-QCZjiKxGHAzDINuVtQhAxpbESRZILsJxkDwslHy2HZCLXcilC-DRqKEQDFBYuMEFyOhWj6ZAAF5XW7AAibSWkUbVCxIUo4AATwdVINifYiX3dE5PBuah-W8VtK1DWsI0bSFmzjedYNspUV1xfEBxzQ9jLM8DzS5Xl+UFWQpxnZA3OrMM6wbKNvNjeD8AXLT0R7VV+yzQdiXCkzTKimgORiq0bVFbDy1neYCDy0jU1VNdCA3ZAt13LVDwvOlkBa-AKQAP0mqbppm2a5sm48T1GnU31MwgUAxXF2PophSR41d12oEB0l2HhoFJEQLqHI1lopE0ixqy04utNaNucjEfjvEQgA)